# Поиск подстрок в строках списков на Python

Tags: python, алгоритм, list, поиск

Существует ли более быстрый способ поиска подстрок в строках списков загружаемых из файлов.

Для конкретики, приведу пример моего кода на Python.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
dirFiles = 'd:/data/'
files = os.listdir(dirFiles) # Файлов в каталоге около 3'000
files.sort()
fileA = open('d:/ListA.txt')
linesA = fileA.readlines() # В файле порядка 50'000 уникальных искомых подстрок
fileA.close()
for fileName in files:
    fileB = open(dirFiles + fileName)
    linesB = fileB.readlines() # В каждом файле порядка 700'000 уникальных строк
    fileB.close()
    for lineA in linesA:
        res = [y for y in linesB if lineA.replace('\n','') in y] # Поиск каждой строки lineA в качестве подстроки в каждой строке списка linesB
        if len(res) > 0:
            print res
```

Код работает очень медленно, и хотелось бы найти способы ускорить поиск.

**Пример искомых подстрок списка linesA:**
sjfrhfereirevb
fvbdjvejeirerer
wiuewuewifwwcb
bvdfkbdvbevkbeee

**Пример строк списка listB, в которых производится поиск:**
djcwjbcbcwiebcwebcerbuevitbbtvietbvndwnecwoewrnen
ewwfsjfrhfereirevbewdownwonewrnoenrviernveonvoenrveornveor
weacewewijernceirvetvnenrvernvernveoitnvetnvenrvoenrverv
euccdwiuewuewifwwcbewcwcwwirbeiwrorjoeroehroverivheiveveeverv

Comment: А там везде именно сроки? Или отдельные слова, например? Без дополнительной информации скорее всего ничего особо не удастся. Ну, разве что многопоточность попробовать, да и то не факт, что что-то даст.

Comment: Тогда мне кажется надо как-то на множества, состоящие из слов, всё перевести. Но надо ещё подумать, как это потом правильно использовать.

Comment: Например, превратить `linesB` из списка строк в список множеств слов. Тогда проверка `if lineA in y` будет выполняться моментально. Возможно, это даст нужное ускорение.

Comment: Вообще может цикл надо делать именно по `linesB`, сразу конструировать из строки множество слов и проверять его на пересечение с множеством `linesA`

Comment: Везде именно строки, без учёта разделителя (пробела).

Comment: Какая средняя длина искомых строк? Какая средняя длина строк в файлах, где проводится поиск? Какая доля успешных поисков? Хочу попробовать `trie`.  Для тестов нужны данные. Собираюсь генерировать.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, средняя длина строк в файлах, где проводится поиск - от 18 символов до 500, на вскидку. Средняя длина искомых строк (подстрок) порядка 65-72 символов. Доля успешных поисков - данный критерий к сожалению не возможно явно определить. Постарался привести пример, отредактировал вопрос.

Comment: Проверьте, пожалуйста, длины строк в файлах. Они не соответствуют примеру.

Answer (score 2):

[Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) или [префиксное дерево](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) хорошо подходит для решения задачи. Это дерево для набора строк. В корне хранится `dict` со всеми возможными первыми символами строк. В узлах внутри тоже хранятся словари с буквами, которыми можно продолжить строку. Признак конца строки - пустой ключ в словаре. Пример:

```
import pprint

def make_trie(iterable):
    root = {}
    for s in iterable:
        node = root
        for c in s:
            node = node.setdefault(c, {})
        node[''] = None
    return root

pprint.pprint(make_trie(('then', 'than', 'thing', 'those')))
```

> ```
> {'t': {'h': {'a': {'n': {'': None}},
>              'e': {'n': {'': None}},
>              'i': {'n': {'g': {'': None}}},
>              'o': {'s': {'e': {'': None}}}}}}
> ```

С помощью префиксного дерева можно проверить, что данный текст содержит какое-нибудь слово из дерева.

Например, чтобы проверить что строка есть в дереве, будем брать из неё символы по одному и спускаться по дереву:

```
s = ...              # строка которую ищем в дереве
node = root          # корень префиксного дерева
for c in s:          # символ за символом ...
    node = node[c]   # ... спускаемся по дереву
```

Если очередного символа в узле не оказалось, то строки в дереве нет. Если последний узел содержит ключ '', то строка в дереве есть.

Так как нам надо проверять не только начало текста, но и любое место внутри, то будем поддерживать список узлов, которые действительны на данном символе. С каждым новым символом текста список пополняется новым элементом - корнем дерева. Все узлы, которые не соответствуют очередному символу из списка удаляются. Чтобы эти операции были быстрыми приходится работать с индексами, что не привычно для Питона:

```
def contains(text, trie):
    if '' in trie:
        return True

    nodes = []
    for c in text:
        nodes.append(trie)  # анализируем строку, которая начинается на этом символе
        i = 0
        while i < len(nodes):
            node = nodes[i]
            if c in node:
                # спуск по дереву
                node = node[c]
                nodes[i] = node
                if '' in node:  # признак конца строки в trie
                    return True
                i += 1
            else:
                # удаляем узел из списка
                nodes[i] = nodes[-1]
                nodes.pop()
    return False
```

Для проверки эффективности trie были изготовлены тестовые данные. Скрипт [generate_sample.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StanislavVolodarskiy/trie/main/generate_sample.py) готовит файл со строками для поиска (50'000 строк от 10 до 20 символов) ...

> ```
> ...
> uctufrxhfomiuwrhvkyy
> hbzkmicgsw
> gupmuoeiehxrrix
> nsmlheqpcybdeufzvnt
> mmtoqiravxd
> ...
> ```

... и текст в котором они ищутся (20'000 строк длиной от 20 до 100 символов) ...

> ```
> ...
> oeosbugxnbfvqgfonutgbzrmmuzumrglpphrqritsiwavmwfvdamrlvulfjswnuzsrhikfybbzxajlfxwhtt
> qizjtyarlbiwnstvtmrqqomblafkhmvwtiocelcyczobausadcudkzykcgyzwajxzkbdwytlnxdqxxycgsdwsyqtn
> xtwlvjyxcisvvbvacljxzmdjrhsueyjffdd
> wyctzgitvbzroiiquohbfostrsvvrorslfevbyhrxqadpytrswk
> fwxeyfmkqavccxgjrtjsikpazaajpknqiizbpbweublcowani
> ...
> ```

В текст с некоторой вероятностью вставлены слова из словаря, чтобы иногда что-то находилось.

Оригинальный поиск на этих данных выполняется 112 секунд. [baseline.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StanislavVolodarskiy/trie/main/baseline.py):

```
with open('patterns.txt') as f:
    patterns = tuple(line.replace('\n','') for line in f)

with open('corpus.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        for p in patterns:
            if p in line:
                print(line, end='')
                break
```

Поиск с помощью `trie` около двух секунд. [trie.py](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/StanislavVolodarskiy/trie/main/trie.py):

```
def make_trie(iterable):
    ...

def contains(text, trie):
    ...

with open('patterns.txt') as f:
    trie = make_trie(line.replace('\n', '') for line in f)

with open('corpus.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.replace('\n','')
        if contains(line, trie):
            print(line)
```

Так как обработка посимвольная, то Питон не лучший кандидат для быстрого решения. Решение на C или C++ должно работать быстрее раз в 10-20 если не больше.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, вместо внутреннего цикла нужно сделать так:

```
# ещё до цикла по файлам
setA = set(linesA)
# ...
for lineB in linesB:
    setB = set(lineB.split())
    if setA & setB:
        print(lineB)
```

P.S. Это для поиска отдельных слов. Если речь всё же о подстроках, как вы указали в последнем изменении вопроса, то, думаю, простого решения тут нет. Хотя можно попробовать в 2 этапа - сначала искать пересечение с множеством слов и если оно есть, тогда искать подстроку, возможно это даст ускорение. Но нужно проверять.